# Errors with python and OpenCV ( error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours') ( too many values to unpack (expected 2))

Tags: python, opencv

So I'm trying to write a code to count all the nuggets in a picture and use a bounding box to show their locations, however whenever I try to run the code these two errors show up:
Exception has occurred: ValueError
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours')

This is the code I have now:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import image, pyplot as plt

image = cv.imread('nuggets.png')
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray,(11,11),0)
canny = cv.Canny(blur, 30, 250, 3)
dilated = cv.dilate(canny, (1,1), iterations=0)
(cnt, hierarchy) = cv.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
rgb = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv.drawContours(rgb,cnt,-1,(0,255,0),2)

print("Nuggets in the image:", len(cnt))
```

Lines 10 and 12 are giving the errors. Any feedback is appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Depending on the OpenCV version, cv2.findContours() has varying return signatures. In v3.4.X, three items are returned. In v2.X and v4.1.X, two items are returned. You can easily obtain the contours regardless of the version like this

Comment: `cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` then `cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]`